# TreeViewItem убрать выделение при открытии контекстного меню

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

Есть такой TreeView:

```
   <TreeView Background="Transparent" Name="myTreeView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FoldersAndFiles, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TreeViewItemStyle}" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=ItemDoubleClick}"
                               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SelectedItemChanged}"
                               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown Event">
                    <local:SetterAction PropertyName="Background" Value="Transpend" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Childs}" 
                    DataType="{x:Type m:ObjectToView}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Margin="0,2,0,2" Padding="4,4,4,4"
                BorderBrush="DimGray" BorderThickness="1"
                CornerRadius="5">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="{Binding Path=Image}"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu Style="{DynamicResource ContextMenuStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Menu}">
                                    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Header}" 
                                                      Command="{Binding Path=Action}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Path}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

И есть стиль к TreeViewItem вынесенный в словарь ресурсов:

```
  <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- Set Highlight Background color -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>

        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <!-- Set Foreground color -->
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0,0"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>        
     </Style>
```

Вопрос: как в таком случае (в рамках MVVM, если это имеет значение) убрать белое выделение при открытии контекстного меню.
[image: выделение]

Comment: Какое белое выделение? Весть приведенный код нужен для воспроизведения проблемы? Вы хотите чтобы при открытии контекстного меню TreeViewItem не получал фокус? Или чтобы это было не видно?

Comment: На скрине же видно, элемент с белым фоном и черным шрифтом, нужно чтобы этого не было, контекстное меню должно открыватся но внешний вид элемента при этом менятся не должен.